# Swift Sprite Kit recreating SKSpriteNode`s

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Currently, I am working at a Sprite Kit game with Swift.

On the Screen, at the beginning, there are 5 Platforms. They are all `SKSpriteNode's` with color, all looking exactly the same.
As the Player moves, the bottom Platform moves out of the screen on the Y-Axis, and a new generated Platform spawns on top of the screen.

Now I am curious, how would be the best way to code the Platforms?
Should I create 5 Platforms, and as they move out of the Screen, they appear on top of the Screen again?
Or do I recreate them again on top of the Screen? There is no limitation of the Platforms.

The Platforms also perform `SKActions`, as for e.g. recolerize after the Player hits a Platform.

Example Code of the Platform:

```
Platform = SKSpriteNode (color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width , height: 25))
Platform.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.size.width / 2, y: 40)
Platform.zPosition = 1
addChild(Platform)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes: Reuse game objects if possible. Each time you instantiate an object will incur some overhead. Avoiding that will always be better.

For instance, you could just set the `Platform.position` to the top of the screen whenever you go out of the bottom bounds of the screen. It shouldn't be difficult, always reuse game objects when possible.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to do it this way. That means, after the `Platform` is reset to the top, I have to remove all the actions made. Thanks for your answer!